# Add audio in the middle of Alexa Skill SSML speak block

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, ssml

I am using Node.js Alexa lib: alexa-sdk

I am trying to embed audio in the middle of an SSML response. I am able to add the audio tag at the end of the SSML response, but not in the middle.

For example:

```
<speak> 
    You did great! 
    <audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/human/amzn_sfx_crowd_applause_05.mp3'/> 
    I had a lot of fun, I hope you did too! 
</speak>
```

When I send the above as the SSML to speak, Alexa simulator synthesizes "You did great!" and stops there.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong or how I can make this work? Does embedding audio tag in the middle of the SSML text not work?

Even the alexa docs has an example with audio in the middle, and that does not work for me in the simulator.

thank you

P.S. I asked this question on the amazon forum almost 10 days ago and no reply, which is not uncommon (not the most active place for help)

Comment: When i paste above mp3 file browser. i get access denied error. You sure you can add that at end and play it correctly?

Comment: try replacing your mp3 file with any other file e.g. https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/home/amzn_sfx_door_open_01.mp3 and let me know if that works

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even the link that you pasted will yield access denied. The audio files will only play from within alexa context. Meaning inside the skill or lambda function, amazon passes some sort of authentication header under the covers to allow the file to be accessible. And like I mentioned above, the file will play just fine if I remove all the text after it. So I do not think that it is a file issue.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your SSML and it is working fine. I tested it in the `Voice & Tone` tab of the Alexa Test Simulator.

Both the mp3 files (one from the comment) are playing in the expected order.

```
<speak> 
    You did great! 
    <audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/home/amzn_sfx_door_open_01.mp3'/>
    I had a lot of fun, I hope you did too! 
    <audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/human/amzn_sfx_crowd_applause_05.mp3'/>
</speak>
```

It doesn't matter where the `<audio>` tag is. It will work even if put it right after the `<speak>` tag

```
<speak> 
    <audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/human/amzn_sfx_crowd_applause_05.mp3'/>
    You did great! 
    I had a lot of fun, I hope you did too! 
</speak>
```

Comment: Suddenly, this started working. I literally did not touch my code for a week and just tried it again now. Weird.
The issue that I am facing now is if I put the audio tag in the beginning. I can see the SSML containing exactly what I want it to say, however, it does not say anything outloud. Would you mind moving the audio tag right after `<speak>` and see if it still works for you? thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot I was trying to figure out where to test this. Trying it in `Voice & Tone` section helped me.